# Transform/round-off decimal numbers in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I am trying to POST a JSON file (using Apache NiFi) onto an app that only accepts values with max 10 decimal places.

JSON format:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2016-04-17",
  "zoom" : 13,
  "dc" : 100,
  "CloudCoverPercentage" : 74.707,
  "mean" : 0.18735192480231655,
  "num" : 127,
  "FirstQuartile" : 0.142807444773004,
  "median" : 0.17882054533925174,
  "max" : 0.32004310344827586,
  "min" : 0.059890294413970674,
  "ThirdQuartile" : 0.22603810187853218,
  "StandardDeviation" : 0.06846369990524923
}
```

Question: How do I transform each decimal value in Apache Nifi, so it would only have 10 decimal places?
I read somewhere that **JoltTransformJSON** can be used for this. How do I write the Jolt Spec for this kind of operation?

Comment: how do you construct this json ? in the first place

Comment: I get that from an API endpoint using invokeHTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UpdateRecord` with a `jsonReader`(Infer Schema), `JsonSetWriter` (Inherit Schema)

**Input:**

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2016-04-17",
  "zoom" : 13,
  "dc" : 100,
  "CloudCoverPercentage" : 74.707,
  "mean" : 0.18735192480231655,
  "num" : 127,
  "FirstQuartile" : 0.142807444773004,
  "median" : 0.17882054533925174,
  "max" : 0.32004310344827586,
  "min" : 0.059890294413970674,
  "ThirdQuartile" : 0.22603810187853218,
  "StandardDeviation" : 0.06846369990524923
}
```

**Output:**

```
[ {
  "timestamp" : "2016-04-17",
  "zoom" : 13,
  "dc" : 100,
  "CloudCoverPercentage" : 74.707,
  "mean" : 0.18735192480231655,
  "num" : 127,
  "FirstQuartile" : 0.142807444773004,
  "median" : 0.1788205453,
  "max" : 0.32004310344827586,
  "min" : 0.059890294413970674,
  "ThirdQuartile" : 0.22603810187853218,
  "StandardDeviation" : 0.06846369990524923
} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot simpler than the executeScript (ECMA) option.